# asp.net, open and display .msg file

Tags: asp.net, parsing, msg

Looking for a solution or guidance, so I can parse the .msg (outlook email) file and display in asp.net (vb.net). Basically, parsing of .msg file is the issue. I try using outlook dll, but there is no sample code, how to load and parse email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you looking is a **MIME message parser**.

There are some free source code that can do the work for you:

http://mailutilities.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11882/Advanced-MIME-Parser-Creator-Editor

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19777/MIME-Compliant-Parser

and one commercial : http://www.aspnetmime.com/

What you do, is that you give your mail, that actually is a text file, and they return you the parts of your email, like Subject, headers, body, etc...

Comment: @sunil, and Aristos, Thanks. I just need to read the articles and figure out the best approach.